# Trying to use ARG Variable inside file path in dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile, environment-variables

I am having some trouble in understanding the inner workings of the ARG feature in a dockerfile. It seems that I can't use variables to parametrize a file path. In order to illustrate the issue, suppose I have a (short) dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

ARG VAR

RUN mkdir -r /test/x

CMD touch /test/$VAR/l
```

I build an image tagged b from this dockerfile with

```
docker build --build-arg VAR=x -t b .
```

and then I run it with

```
docker run -v '.:/test' b
```

Why isn't there a folder named x with a file named l inside my working directory?

Can't I use variables within file paths in a dockerfile?

This is an abstraction of a larger problem I am facing while building a CI/CD architecture for PBI. I was expecting that I would be able to use variables defined by ARG withing file paths.

I think I would be able to reduce the problem to a more fundamental issue, if necessary. However, this example should be enough to illustrate the question.

I am new to SO, and I hope that my question is sufficiently well explained.

Comment: Dockerfile `ARG` doesn't affect the runtime environment of the eventual container; the `CMD` isn't evaluated until the container starts, and the `ARG`s no longer have an effect.

Comment: More generally, I wouldn't usually recommend trying to parameterize file paths like this.  Consider the `/test` directory: you've used that directory name as part of your container's external interface (as a known supported mount point) and so it kind of needs to be fixed.  My experience has generally been that using a fixed filesystem layout in a container is fine, and trying to keep everything inside a single directory with a short name (`/app` for example) simplifies using it.